# Design is on top of top bar

Tags: bug, status-planned, design

The circle that *was* part of the background now overlaps the top bar like in the pictures below:

[image]

[image]

This should be fixed, because it wasn't like this before.

Comment: It’s probably the prelude of [the new top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300829/255554). I briefly saw this before the new top bar was activated for moderators.

Comment: That being said, I like it.

Comment: works fine on my screen

Comment: What OS and browser are you using? What version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both these elements have been redesigned and replaced or moved. I can't remember the last time I saw this issue with the top bar and the design overlapping, so I think this is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (and probably has been for a while).