# Design is on top of Code of Conduct announcement

Tags: bug, design

The circle that *was* part of the background now overlaps the Code of Conduct like in the picture below:

[image]

If this all seems very familiar that's because it's a near copy of a bug I reported before (which itself has been fixed for a while): [Design is on top of top bar](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3312/79217).

Comment: I actually like it like that :D

Comment: Me too, I thought it was intentional.